# printf: Difference between \n and %n

Tags: java

Using Java's `String.format` and `System.out.printf`, both `\n` and `%n` provide a newline. Which one should I use and in which situation?

Comment: `%n` is the **platform-specific** line separator.

Comment: Related: [What's up with Java's “%n” in printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883345/whats-up-with-javas-n-in-printf)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: that should be an answer.

Comment: @PakkuDon: This is basically a duplicate of that...