# Java - toString Formatting (Formatting Doubles)

Tags: java, formatting, tostring

The project I am working on requires a bank account balance to be printed using a toString method.  I am not allowed to add any methods to my current program, but I need to format my myBalance variable to a double that goes to two decimal places instead of one.  In this particular instance my program should be printing 8.03, but it is printing 8.0.

**Here is my toString method:**

```
   public String toString()
   {
      return"SavingsAccount[owner: " + myName + 
      ", balance: " + myBalance + 
      ", interest rate: " + myInterestRate + 
      ",\n number of withdrawals this month: " + myMonthlyWithdrawCount + 
      ", service charges for this month: " + 
      myMonthlyServiceCharges + ", myStatusIsActive: " +
      myStatusIsActive + "]";
   }
```

I am very new to Java still, so I would like to know if there is a way to implement %.2f into the string somewhere to format only the myBalance variable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.format(...)` for this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SavingsAccount[owner: " + myName + 
    ", balance: " + String.format("%.2f", myBalance) + 
    ", interest rate: " + String.format("%.2f", myInterestRate) + 
    ",\n number of withdrawals this month: " + myMonthlyWithdrawCount + 
    ", service charges for this month: " + 
    myMonthlyServiceCharges + ", myStatusIsActive: " +
    myStatusIsActive + "]";
}
```

or more succinctly:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = String.format("[owner: %s, balance: %.2f, interest rate: %.2f%n" +
        "number of withdrawals this month: %d, service charges for this month: %.2f, " + 
        "myStatusIsActive: %s]",
        myName, myBalance, myInterestRate, myMonthlyWithdrawCount, 
        myMonthlyServiceCharges, myStatusIsActive);
    return result;
}
```

Note that khelwood asked about my use of `"%n"` for a new-line token rather than the usual `"\n"` String. I use `%n` because this will allow the `java.util.Formatter` to get a platform specific new-line, useful in particular if I want to write the String to a file. Note that `String.format(...)` as well as `System.out.printf(...)` and similar methods use `java.util.Formatter` in the background so this applies to them as well.

Comment: I see!  I was unaware you could write it like that.  Thank you very much sir/madam.  Also, I love you username.

Comment: Do you mean `\n` where you have `%n` ?

Comment: @khelwood: no, I absolutely mean `%n` and not `\n`. When using java.util.Formatter (which is what `String.format(...)` uses) you should avoid use of `\n` and use `%n` preferentially.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Cheers.

Comment: @khelwood: no problem. Note that it allows for platform specific new lines as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883345/whats-up-with-javas-n-in-printf). Note that printf also uses `java.util.Formatter` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.format()

Example :

```
Double value = 8.030989;
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", value));
```

Output :
  8.03

Comment: possible duplicate of  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885254/string-format-to-format-double-in-java)