# How do I print a percent sign in java with printf?

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I'm new to Java...

Can anyone tell me how to get my percent sign to show up in my code?

Thanks,

```
System.out.printf("\n Your body fat is: %3.2f" , bodyFatPercentage , "% \n");
```

Comment: Sorry about the duplication...thanks for the re-direct!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, for `printf`, [it's better to use `%n` instead of `\n` so that it's cross-platform](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1883364/5743988).

Comment: Use `%%`. But more importantly, first go to the API for System, then for PrintStream (the class for `out`) and then check the printf method. It will refer you to the Formatter API and you should check there how to print %.

Comment: Awesome...thanks for the tips.