# java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'N'

Tags: type-conversion, format-conversion

This is my code:

```
package com.example.java;

public class PackageDataTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PackageData data1 = new PackageData("John Davids");
        System.out.printf("%Number of object created until now is : %d", PackageData.count);
    }
}

class PackageData {

    static int count = 0;
    String name;

    public PackageData(){
        this.name = "";
        ++count;
    }

    public PackageData(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        ++count;
    }

    public int getCount() { return count; }
}
```

I keep receiving the following error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'N'"

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE]. As is stands the question is a debugging question which is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%N is not a valid conversion Format and %n is for the line break.

so if you replace the code as below:

```
System.out.printf("%nNumber of object created until now is : %d", PackageData.count);
```

output will be on new line:

```
Number of object created until now is : 1
```

check this discussion: [What's up with Java's "%n" in printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883345/whats-up-with-javas-n-in-printf)