# round to 2 decimal point using string.format .places java

Tags: java

my homework exercise gave skeleton of attendaces and my job was to name weeks so it maches values in arrays and get avarage attendance for each week and get output 
and the code is:

```
public class AttendanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Integer CLASS_SIZE = 15;
        Integer[] attendances = {10, 14, 12, 9, 11, 15, 12, 13, 8, 14};
        final Integer ACADEMIC_WEEKS = 10;
        final String[] weeks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        Double totalAvg;

        for (Integer week = 0; week < ACADEMIC_WEEKS; week++) {
            totalAvg = (double)(attendances[week]*100)/CLASS_SIZE;
            System.out.println(weeks[week] + "    " +totalAvg);
        }
    }
}
```

and gives output of:

> ```
> 1    66.66666666666667
> 2    93.33333333333333
> 3    80.0
> 4    60.0
> 5    73.33333333333333
> 6    100.0
> 7    80.0
> 8    86.66666666666667
> 9    53.333333333333336
> 10    93.33333333333333
> ```

how can i round the output to 2 decimal point using String.format and/or .places?

so the output will be:

> ```
> 1   66.67
> 2   93.33
> 3   80.00
> 4   60.00
> 5   73.33
> 6  100.00
> 7   80.00
> 8   86.67
> 9   53.33
> 10  93.33
> ```

Comment: look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701399/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: `String.format("%1$.2d",1.234567f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf`, not `println`:

```
System.out.printf("%s\t%.2f%n", weeks[week], totalAvg);
```

- `%s` prints the first parameter given as **string**
- `\t` prints a **tab**
- `%.2f` prints the second parameter given as **float** with 2 decimal digits
- `%n` prints a new line

Comment: im not sure why but the output is:"
1 66,672 93,333 80,004 60,005 73,336 100,007 80,008 86,679 53,3310 93,33"

im not sure where did that 1 came from and it doesnt round to well

Comment: You need to add `%n` at the end of the format to have a newline (like `println`

Comment: Forgot the \n at the end

Comment: `\n` is OS dependent, not `%n`, see [What's up with Java's “%n” in printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883345/whats-up-with-javas-n-in-printf)

Comment: You’re right, thanks

Comment: In the end, everything is explained in [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). This is a must to read !