# How to print multiple System.out.printf statements in to one line?

Tags: java

I want to put two printf statement lines as a one line. I tried but could not do it. I need help. Thank you in advance.

Here is the statements:

```
System.out.printf("%s%n%s: $%,.2f%n",currentEmployee,"payroll",currentEmployee.earnings());

System.out.printf("birthday bonus: $100.00 = $%,.2f%n%n", currentEmployee.earnings()+100);
```

Comment: `"%s%n%s: $%,.2f%n"` do you know what `%n` means?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883345/whats-up-with-javas-n-in-printf and you will end up fixing your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I was able to fix the issue.